# Como cargar ruta de index luego de llamar la funcion buscar para que luego de buscar en la pagina index en Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, crud

El crud funciona pero me di cuenta que desde la vista que vota el search no puedo ir a nuevo , ya que no estoy en la vista index, como hago para que me muestre el campo que busco pero vuelva a la vista index.

[image: Esta es la direccion de vista que me carga]

```
introducir el código aquí Código del search en el index
> div class="col-md-4">
<form action="/search" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class='btn btn-warning'>Buscar</button>
        </span>
    </div>                    
</form>
```

[image: EStas son mis rutas]

```
Este es el Controller

   public function search(Request $request){
    $search = $request->get('search');
            $estudiantes= DB::table('estudiantes')
                ->where('idEstudiante', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                    ->paginate(5);
            return view('BaseDatos/estudiantes.index', ["estudiantes" => $estudiantes]);
```

[image: ROUTES]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor volvé a redactar la pregunta porque no se entiende. Qué significa que *no podes ir a nuevo*? Está mal esa URL? Publicá el código HTML de esa vista. Y lo que puedas publicar como código, publicalo como texto, no como imagen (como las rutas).

Comment: la vista que muestro es la que sale cuando se consulta un registro, pero el botom de Nuevo ya no me lleva a ningun lado, no tiene ruta definida como hago para que esto no suceda

Comment: Publicá el código de la vista.

Comment: que pena la duda como puedo publicar de nuevo el codigo de esa vista en los comentarios no me deja

Comment: Debajo de la pregunta tendrías que tener un botón que dice "editar", hacés click ahí y editás tu pregunta.

Comment: que pena que lo cargue asi pero despues del boton buscar no me aceptaba sino parte del código y luego se amontonaba todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la imagen se ve que la uri de la ruta a la que quieres apuntar con el *enlace* donde está el botón **Nuevo**, es `BaseDatos/estudiantes/create`, y no `estudiantes/create`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ver, además de otros datos, la **`URI`** y el nombre **`Name`** de la ruta que corresponde, en el listado de rutas.

Una vez resuelto eso, llegan los ayudantes de Laravel, como el helper [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route) para llamar a la ruta por su nombre:

> La función `route` genera una URL para la ruta con el nombre dado.

```
href="{{  route('estudiantes.create') }}"
```

O el helper [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url):

> La función `url` genera una URL completa para la uri dada.

```
href="{{  url('BaseDatos/estudiantes/create') }}"
```

Comment: Asumia que era por ahí pero en los tutoriales que he visto no usaban esa notación y cuando la cambiaba usando las que veía nunca funciono, muchas gracias crack.

Comment: Sí, son helpers (ayudantes) de Laravel.  > Funciones PHP "auxiliares" globales. Actualicé la respuesta tratando de explicarlo un poco mejor.